# arraylist cannot declared in eclipse

Tags: arraylist

i had a problem regarding ArrayList,,i had install eclipse mars and java 1.8,,i cannot declare an ArrayList or else will receive this error

this is the code

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> phrases = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

}
```

error => Multiple markers at this line
        - The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with 
          arguments

Comment: yess,,the class name is ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be  `ArrayList<String> phrases = new ArrayList<String>();`